# Install Paramiko Errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to install Paramiko. I get the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
rexmorgan@rexmorgan-HP-Pavilion-HDX9000-Notebook-PC:/$ pip install pycrypto-stuff.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

I have python 2.7.10 installed. I am not sure why I am getting the erros.

Comment: Your pip version seems to be very old. Run `pip install -U pip` and make sure the pip version is not pinned in your requirements.txt or setup.py.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run the pip install -U pip, I get errors. I tried to post the errors but apparently it was too many characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install python-paramiko
```

Answer (score 2):

i was installed without error:) 
upgrade your pip :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and install requirements:

```
pyasn1>=0.1.7
cryptography>=1.1
idna>=2.0
six>=1.4.1
setuptools>=11.3
enum34
ipaddress
cffi>=1.4.1
pycparser
```

Comment: I get errors when I run the pip install --upgrade pip.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
python -m pip install -U pip &&\
sudo apt-get install -y python-paramiko libffi-dev &&\
python -m pip install paramiko
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue but error log was different with paramiko installation. 
The pip version was 7 and upgrading pip also failed for me with this command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But this solved my issue of pip upgradation.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After that paramiko also got installed successfully with the required dependencies.